# Trouble freezing (with PyInstaller) python source including multiprocessing module in Solaris

Tags: python, multiprocessing, solaris, pyinstaller

I'm trying to freeze and distribute among my Solaris11 machines the following python code which makes use of multiprocessing module:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('fer',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

However, even if the executable works fine under the compiler machine (Solaris11) ...

```
[root@zgv-wodbuild01 pyinstaller]# testfer/dist/testfer
hello fer
[root@zgv-wodbuild01 pyinstaller]# echo $?
0
```

...complains about multiprocessing library in any other machine (Solaris11):

```
root@dest01a # ./testfer.r004 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testfer.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/root/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
File "multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
File "/root/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: ld.so.1: testfer.r004: fatal: relocation error: file /tmp/_MEIlBa4uh/_multiprocessing.so: symbol __xnet_sendmsg: referenced symbol not found
Failed to execute script testfer
root@dest01a # echo $?
255
```

PyInstaller command has been launched with `--onefile` flag so every needed library should be included inside final ELF file (multiprocessing too). But I have also tried to include explicitly multiprocessing library by editing `hidden-import` section in the .spec file.

I have also tried to freeze the source in an older Solaris 10 machine to ensure backwards compatibility. Compiling the PyInstaller bootloaders both with and without special LDFLAGS like `-lrt`. Using `--debug` flag. But so far nothing worked nor gave me a clue.

Apparently the binary is properly built for the right architecture and there is no library issues:

```
root@dest01a # file testfer.r004 
testfer.r004:   ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC1 Extensions Required, dynamically linked, stripped

root@dest01a # crle 
Platform:     32-bit MSB SPARC
Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib  (system default)
Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)

root@dest01a # ldd -r testfer.r004 
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        libz.so.1 =>     /lib/libz.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1

root@dest01a # ldd -r /lib/libsocket.so.1 
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libsoftcrypto.so.1 =>    /lib/libsoftcrypto.so.1
        libelf.so.1 =>   /lib/libelf.so.1
        libcryptoutil.so.1 =>    /lib/libcryptoutil.so.1
        libz.so.1 =>     /lib/libz.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
```

So I ran out of ideas.
Thanks in advance for any insight.

**Update**: Thanks to Andrew Henle comments I've been able to make some progress. I have recompiled the PyInstaller bootloaders again but this time establishing LDFLAGS environment variable to `LDFLAGS="-lsocket -lrt"`.

Now it's not complaining about `__xnet` symbols anymore but `symbol get_fips_mode` instead. As you can see:

```
root@lnrep01a # ./testfer.r004 
ld.so.1: testfer.r004: fatal: relocation error: file /lib/libsoftcrypto.so.1: symbol get_fips_mode: referenced symbol not found
Killed
```

So probably I just need to add some extra flags to compiling process. I will look for them across the internet but if someone knows what is missing, that would be more than welcome.

Comment: `ldd` with no options won't tell you there are no library issues.  It just tells you that all the requested libraries can be found - not that all symbols used can be found, or that you're missing a library entirely.  Try `ldd -r ...` to force all required relocations.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ldd-1.html  It looks like you're missing a dependency on `libsocket.so`.

Comment: You're right. I had also tried that yesterday but apparently everything is fine about `libsocket.so` both in compiler machine and in the destination machine. I have edited the post to show `ldd -r` outputs.

Comment: You still get `symbol __xnet_sendmsg: referenced symbol not found` when running `./testfer.r004`, then?

Comment: Yes, still getting same `symbol __xnet_sendmsg: referenced symbol not found` error. I've added part of `truss` output right before it crashes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the `truss` with some more options - it looks like a child process is failing - probably a compile of some type, given the last file opened was a `Makefile`.  Try `truss -f -e ...`.  You'll probably want to also add a `-o /path/to/output/file` option also, as the process tree is likely to generate a lot of output.  (`-f` means follow child process also, `-e` causes the environment to be included for `execve` calls)

Comment: Post edited to add `-f -e` flags to `truss` command output.

Comment: The `truss` output you posted is the printing of the error messages, not what caused the printing of the error messages.  The information needed to solve this problem is almost certainly somewhere in that `truss` output.  You need to find it.  It's likely that whatever is in that Makefile mistakenly omits a `-lsocket` somewhere in a link step.

Comment: Your last comment has been very useful, As you can see in the updated post, We're closer to the solution.

Comment: That looks like a possible GCC bug:  https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-08/msg01055.html

Comment: But I'm using `gcc (GCC) 4.8.2`

Comment: However you seems to be right about the bug thing because I have reproduced same steps in Solaris 10 (now with -lsocket) and it's working fine both in compiler machine (solaris 10) as in the destination (solaris 11).
Then if I want to fix that bug in Sol11 I have to edit the header file and re-compile gcc again, right?

Comment: *if I want to fix that bug in Sol11 I have to edit the header file and re-compile gcc again, right?*  I can't say - I'm not familiar with that bug at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it wasn't a gcc bug. After analysing in depth both environments, I realized the `/lib/libsoftcrypto.so.1` libraries differs a lot. As a matter of fact, the library in the compiler machine contains `get_fips_mode` symbol...

```
[root@zgv-wodbuild01 pyinstaller]# nm /lib/libsoftcrypto.so.1  | grep -i get_fips_mode
[3438]  |    623016|       212|FUNC |GLOB |0    |18     |get_fips_mode
```

...while the destination machine does not:

```
root@dest01a # nm /lib/libsoftcrypto.so.1  | grep -i get_fips_mode
[3755]  |         0|         0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |get_fips_mode
```

After trying another compiler machine with similar library version, compiling the pyinstaller bootloaders with `-lsocket` ldflag was enough:

```
root@dest01a # ./testferv3
hello fer
root@dest01a # echo $?
0
```